# iOS Unable to find a build in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted to the itunes builds, had just finished to submit in activity can see is processing, when one minute to refresh the page, and build the activity inside, there is no filed, a all have no, I submitted for so many times, who met this problem?

Comment: I did face the same problem, uploaded almost 15 binaries. When you are submitting the binary are there any warning or errors?

Comment: There are no warnings and errors, Xcode to remind me to upload a success, I found the reason, apple sent me email, I forgot to see mail, E-mail said added a wrong file：Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link 'mapapi.bundle/libsqlite3.0.tbd' which resolves to a location 'mapapi.bundle/libsqlite3.tbd' that does not exist or is outside of the package.

Comment: Great, happy coding man

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to wait for minutes/hours. If the build will not appear in 24 hours (maximal delay I've experienced) - contact apple support.

Comment: Thanks and I found the reason, apple sent me email, I forgot to see mail, E-mail said added a wrong file：Invalid Symlink - Your package contains a symbolic link 'mapapi.bundle/libsqlite3.0.tbd' which resolves to a location 'mapapi.bundle/libsqlite3.tbd' that does not exist or is outside of the package.I modified the file